# could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAPKCopy'

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

it seems that I got this problem when I try to run the app

[image: the error]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This can happen when there is an error in an update. To fix it open android sdk manager and:

- Uninstall android support repository
- Install again android support repository

Comment: How to uninstall and uninstall. All it shows a delete package button. I clicked and it's gone. No longer appearing for installation.  Can you share the steps?

Comment: i think you just need to click the check mark in square to uninstall and instal very simple

Comment: I'm still receiving this error after uninstalling/reinstalling the support repo. This happens to be on a new OS install. Is there something else that needs configuring?

Comment: I had no success with this suggestion either. I still get `Could not find org.webkit:android-jsc:r224109.` Not sure if it's important, but I found this in `app/build.gradle` 

```configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r224109'
    }
}```

Comment: I got this error after installing a new OS (Big Sur) and accepting Google agreement fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 7):

Install `Android Support Repository` in SDK Manager.

Add dedependencies to build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: yay -S android-support-repository if you are on arch

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me while opening Android Studio to resolve the dependencies

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       mavenLocal()
       jcenter()
          maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com'
          }
       maven {
           url "https://jitpack.io"
       }
       maven {
           // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed 
 from npm 
              url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

"Build > Clean Project"  worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Change `jcenter()` to `mavenCentral()` in **project** level **build.gradle**

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this error.

This error resolved by updating Android Support Repository.

Another way to solve this error is go to your `build.gradle` file and check for warnings related to support version dependencies. then look for hint, make change as it suggested. 
In my case this error caused by support dependencies:-

- `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'`

and I changed to :-

- `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'`

Answer (score 2):

For me it was only a pending update of the Google Repository.Mine Android Support Repository was already updated, so i update Google repository and it works for me

**Update the Google Repository!**

Answer (score 1):

For me it was only a pending update of the `Android Support Repository`.

**Update the `Android Support Repository`!**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the right version of Android SDK Platform-tools installed. Your project might be configured for a different version. To do this got to Settings>android sdk> sdk tools > show package details, then choose the version compatible with your project and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted this in the build.gradle module and it worked.

```
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the buildToolsVersion from "33.0.0" to "33.0.2" worked for me.