# Unable to update the Firebase dependency(com.google.firebase)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have Added Firebase to android app for push notification. I have updated build.gradle before i have used. Its working fine.

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
```

now i have updated to latest library but getting error.

```
 dependencies {
  //....
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'       
  }
```

I had getting error at the time of Rebuild project

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            DGApp:app:unspecified

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check my answer here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop/38224316#38224316 it may be helpful

Comment: Did you updated your support library recently ?.Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39302669/3111083.

Comment: Thank you. Now i am udating my SDK to latest.

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: Please see my answer :). Oh and +1 for this great question, I actually had this problem and I solved it myself, therefor I added an answer :)

Answer (score 20):

You have to update your Google Play Services and Google Repository from the Standalone SDK Manager.

**Edit:** As of the latest version of Android Studio the Standalone SDK Manager is removed. You must go to the SDK Tools tab.

First off, open Android Studio and click this icon at the top toolbar:

[image]

Then, when the dialog launches, click "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" at the bottom left of the dialog:

[image]

To make sure nothing other than what we want gets updated/installed, click "Deselect All":

[image]

When the Standalone SDK Manager window opens, look for "Extras" and collapse it. You should see "Google Play Services" and "Google Repository" and on the right you should see *"Update Available: {something}"*. Select these to items and click "Install".

[image]

When they're done installing, the error will go away.

Comment: @NitinKarande did it work? If not, make sure you're updating "Google Play Services" and "Google Repository" and not some other SDK

Answer (score 4):

Add the google-services plugin

In build.gradle file, to include the google-services plugin:

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
```

Then, in your module Gradle file (usually the app/build.gradle), add the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
// ...
 }

dependencies {
 // ...
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

// Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
// the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
 }

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[More details refer Firebase setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Answer (score 2):

If you read documentation they are indicating you update your latest `Google Repository in the Android SDK manager`

So just go to `Android SDK Manager` and `install the latest version of below two libraries`

1-Google Play Services

2-Google Repository

Check the image from documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager.

To reseolved the problem;

- Open SDK Manager and update the SDK Tools for latest especially Google APIs under Android 7.0(API 24)

Answer (score -2):

May be you are not giving the right repo.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



}
```