# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1

Tags: firebase

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':messaging:app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':messaging:app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :messaging:app
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :messaging:app

Answer (score 9):

As you can read on these answers:

[Unable to update the Firebase dependency(com.google.firebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858208/unable-to-update-the-firebase-dependencycom-google-firebase)

[Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0)

You need to update the Google Play Services and Google Repository because your libraries are deprecated.

I Hope it helps