# Adding Firebase to Android Application

Tags: android, firebase

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ah9VrF3enA).

I've done a quite of bit of research trying to fix this problem. I updated google services and google repository in the sdk manager. Iv'e tried about everything that was suggested but still can't sync my android project and now I can't even build or run my project since I first tried to sync. Here is a screen shot of my project. Everything went well until this point.

Error

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to update the Firebase dependency(com.google.firebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858208/unable-to-update-the-firebase-dependencycom-google-firebase)

Answer (score 2):

The build.gradle file you posted is the project-level file.  Remove the last line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and instead, place it as the last line of your app module build.gradle file (the one under `app`).