# react-native android build fails: Could not find org.webkit:android-jsc:r224109

Tags: android, react-native, build, build.gradle

I had no success with this suggestion: [could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAPKCopy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090248/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-appdebugapkcopy)
. I still get

`Could not find org.webkit:android-jsc:r224109.`

Not sure if it's important, but I found this in `app/build.gradle`

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
      force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r224109'
  }
}
```

Any have experience resolving this problem? My app builds on iOS with no trouble.

EDIT: My app contains all the config changes described in this doc https://github.com/react-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#how-to-use-it-with-my-react-native-app

Comment: Apparently, something went terribly wrong w/ my environment. I rebuilt android setup from scratch. Now it works. IDK.